# tor cant connect to tor network mac

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

When I try to launch Tor I get a pop up saying "Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself. another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you restart Tor, the Tor Browser will not able to reach any websites. If the program persists, please send a copy of your Tor Log to the support team."

Comment: Do you have a copy of your log? To do this, run Tor from a terminal, and pass it the `-v` option as an argument. Then edit your question to include your logs.

Comment: no i dont have a copy of my log and i not sure how to use terminal to find out.what command should i use?